# Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::users does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-8

I am trying to attach the roles, users, and users_role tables. Trying to connect them and checking on the Blade file that if a user's role is admin, he can only access the user's route; otherwise, he can't access it. For other users, the users' route must not be seen. At the same time, verifying code on the Blade file throws an error. How can I solve this in the latest Laravel 8?

**app.blade.php**

```
@if(Auth::users()->roles()->where('name', 'Admin')->exists())
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/Admin/users')}}">Users</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/Admin/Posts')}}">Posts</a>
    </li>
@else
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/Admin/Posts')}}">Posts</a>
    </li>
@endif
```

**Role model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id')
        ->using(UserRole::class);
}
```

**User model**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(role::class, 'users_roles', 'role_id',
        'user_id')->using(UserRole::class)->withPivot('name');
}
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar Oad  do you know how to solve the error

Comment: yes i have solve it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Replace this

```
@if(Auth::users()->roles()->where('name', 'Admin')->exists())
```

Into

```
@if(\Auth::user()->roles =='Admin')
```

I hope you got your solution .

Comment: sorry but what you did.. not able to understand it .. is this my query right for checking the role???

Comment: now i have updated my answer tell me if you have any problem

Comment: @Rkesh Kumar Oad ??

Comment: still not getting result same error... could we use user instead of users , but getting another error

Comment: after updating the code getting new error:----    Trying to get property 'roles' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara-media\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Comment: fully not but half done.. thanks @Rakesh Kumar Oad

Answer (score 0):

with the help of rakesh answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68176136/16114539
and some modification , the error got solved ..
so you can check the current user and check role of it and then show it the code is like:

```
    @if(Auth::check() &&  Auth::user()->roles()->where('name', 'Admin')->exists())
```

it get solved